# Read large csv file and join in r

Tags: r, read.csv

I have a large csv file which is of size around 2.5 GB, I want to read that file from directory and join with the other dictionary csv file and keep the rows that are matching with the one particular column dictionary file in r. How do I do it? I tried with fread method but this doesn't works.

Comment: what didn't work with `fread`? show the code you used and what was the problem with it

Comment: Raw_files_list <- dir(Data_Folder, recursive=TRUE, full.names=TRUE, pattern="\\.csv$")
RAW_Files = data.table(rbindlist(lapply(Raw_files_list, fread))                              
Was running this code and Was waiting for 1hr to r to read file but still it was not read.

Comment: how many files do you have to read? `fread` shows progress indicator on reading large files - do you see it? what was the progress at 1h?

Comment: I have single file which is of 2.5GB

Comment: with a single file, you don't need all that `rbindlist`, `lapply` etc. - just a single command `dt1 <- fread('path/to/your/file.csv')` - let us know if that works.

Comment: Ya this worked perfectly. Thank You.   On top of it file had more column values than column headers, I used fill = TRUE,header = TRUE.